# How to handle unicode characters with pandas and printing to screen?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, unicode

I'm handling a spreadsheet that contains a series of unicode characters (ransomware names).

At the moment I have the following:

```
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

SOURCESHEET = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TWS238xacAto-fLKh1n5uTsdijWdCEsGIM0Y0Hvmc5g/pub?output=xlsx'
WORKBOOK = 'RansomwareOverview.xlsx'

# download and save ransomware overview file locally
try:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(SOURCESHEET, WORKBOOK)
except IOError:
    print('An error occured trying to write an updated spreadsheet. Do you already have it open?')
except urllib.error.URLError:
    print('An error occured trying to download the file. Please check the source and try again')

sheet = pd.read_excel(open(WORKBOOK,'rb'), sheetname='Ransomware')
print(sheet)
```

When I attempt to `print` the contents of sheet I receive the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "GoogleSpreadsheetToJson.py", line 27, in 
>       print(sheet)   File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
>       return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in
>   position 10917-10922: character maps to

I believe it's because the sheet I'm using has the following properties:

> "ПРОЧТИ_МЕНЯ.txt READ_ME.txt"

Is there a way I can handle, or passover this whilst still using pandas for my spreadsheet?

Comment: Does your terminal support unicode?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I hadn't considered that. I'll test it on bash now and update...

Comment: I have seen `UnicodeEncodeError` when I try to `print` to a terminal that doesn't support unicode before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options:

1. Switch to Python 3.6, which uses Windows' Unicode APIs to write to the console instead of trying to encode to output in cp850 (the console's default encoding on your system).
2. Change the console encoding with `chcp 65001` (UTF-8).
3. Set the environment variable `pythonioencoding=cp850:replace` before running the script.  This changes the error handler from `strict` to `replace`.  You'll get question marks for characters not supported by cp850.

Comment: Python 3.4... so close! I'll update and pull. Thanks for the advice!